# Tkinter button not functioning properly

Tags: tkinter

This is my code, I am trying to make it so that when I press a button, a specific text shows up

```
from tkinter import *

def greet():
    label.config(text = "Hi there!")

root = Tk()
root.title("Placing a button")

button = Button(root, text = "Click here", command = greet).pack()
label = Label(root, text = "   n ").pack()





root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run it and click the button, I get this error:

```
label.config(text = "Hi there!")
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.pack()` on your label will return None. This means

```
label = Label(root, text = "   n ").pack()
```

is now `label = None`. In order to do what you want to do you need to edit your code to this

```
from tkinter import *

def greet():
    label.config(text = "Hi there!")

root = Tk()
root.title("Placing a button")

button = Button(root, text = "Click here", command = greet).pack()
label = Label(root, text = "   n ")
label.pack()





root.mainloop()
```

This way `label` is no longer `None`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps!